# Query only the first detail record for each master record

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

If I have the following master-detail relationship:

```
owner_tbl     auto_tbl
---------     --------
owner    ---> owner
              auto
              year
```

And I have the following table data:

```
owner_tbl     auto_tbl
---------     --------
john          john, corvette, 1968
              john, prius, 2008
james         james, f-150, 2004
              james, cadillac, 2002
              james, accord, 2009
jeff          jeff, tesla, 2010
              jeff, hyundai, 1996
```

Now, I want to perform a query that returns the following result:

```
john, corvette, 1968
jeff, hyundai, 1996
james, cadillac, 2002
```

The query should join the two tables, and sort all the records on the "year" field, but only return the first detail record for each master record.  I know how to join the tables and sort on the "year" field, but it's not clear how (or if) I might be able to only retrieve the first joined record for each owner.

Three related questions:

1. Can I perform this kind of query using LINQ-to-SQL?
2. Can I perform the query using T-SQL?
3. Would it be best to just create a stored procedure for the query given its likely complexity?

Comment: Yes, you can perform the queries. Do you want somebody to write them for you?

Comment: use top command..somewhat
select top 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *Sql Server 2005+* you can try (Full example)

```
DECLARE @owner_tbl TABLE(
        [owner] VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @auto_tbl TABLE(
        [owner] VARCHAR(50),
        [auto] VARCHAR(50),
        [year]VARCHAR(4)
)

INSERT INTO @owner_tbl SELECT 'john'
INSERT INTO @owner_tbl SELECT 'james'
INSERT INTO @owner_tbl SELECT 'jeff'        

INSERT INTO @auto_tbl SELECT 'john','corvette','1968'
INSERT INTO @auto_tbl SELECT 'john','prius','2008'
INSERT INTO @auto_tbl SELECT 'james','f-150','2004'
INSERT INTO @auto_tbl SELECT 'james','cadillac','2002'
INSERT INTO @auto_tbl SELECT 'james','accord','2009'
INSERT INTO @auto_tbl SELECT 'jeff','tesla','2010'
INSERT INTO @auto_tbl SELECT 'jeff','hyundai','1996'

;WITH Autos AS(
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.owner ORDER BY a.year) ROWID
        FROM    @auto_tbl a
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Autos
WHERE   ROWID = 1
ORDER BY owner
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use cross apply :

```
SELECT Owner, X.Car,X.Year
FROM Owener_tbl O
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Auto_tbl WHERE Owner=O.Owner ORDER BY Year ASC
) X
```

Answer (score 1):

c# linq2sql:

```
var results = db.owner_tbls.Select(p=>p.auto_tbls.OrderBy(q=>q.year).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
SELECT o.owner, a.auto, a.EarliestYear
FROM owner_tbl o
INNER JOIN (SELECT owner, auto, min(year) As EarliestYear FROM auto_tbl 
GROUP BY owner, auto) a ON o.owner = a.owner
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample LINQ/LINQPad script...returns your desired results without massive nested queries for each field on the Autos you would potentially filter/select.

```
var Owners = new [] { new { Name = "John" }, new { Name = "James" }, new { Name = "Jeff" } };
var Autos = new [] { 
    new { Owner = "John", Auto = "Corvette", Year = 1968 },
    new { Owner = "John", Auto = "Prius", Year = 2008 },
    new { Owner = "James", Auto = "F-150", Year = 2004 },
    new { Owner = "James", Auto = "Cadillac", Year = 2002 },
    new { Owner = "James", Auto = "Accord", Year = 2009 },
    new { Owner = "Jeff", Auto = "Tesla", Year = 2010 },
    new { Owner = "Jeff", Auto = "Hyundai", Year = 1996 }
};

var results = from o in Owners
              join c in Autos.OrderBy( a => a.Year )
                             .GroupBy( g => g.Owner )
                             .Select( a => a.FirstOrDefault() )
                     on o.Name equals c.Owner
              orderby o.Name descending
              select new { o.Name, c.Auto, c.Year };

results.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using a subquery that returns only the oldest car for each owner that has at least one car.

```
SELECT owner_tbl.owner
, auto_tbl.auto
, auto_tbl.year
FROM owner_tbl
, auto_tbl
WHERE owner_tbl.owner = auto_tbl.owner
AND auto_tbl.auto IN
  (SELECT TOP 1 auto 
  FROM auto_tbl 
  WHERE owner = owner_tbl.owner
  ORDER BY year)
ORDER BY owner_tbl.owner
```